# Google maps not found

Tags: android, google-maps

I have gone through previous posts regarding this issue and have followed the recommendations. 
My app still fails.

Any clue?

**Logcat:**

```
03-17 17:44:20.271: D/AndroidRuntime(455): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
03-17 17:44:20.389: D/AndroidRuntime(455): CheckJNI is ON
03-17 17:44:28.254: D/AndroidRuntime(455): --- registering native functions ---
03-17 17:44:37.919: D/dalvikvm(213): GC_EXPLICIT freed 165 objects / 11896 bytes in 3274ms
03-17 17:44:38.801: D/PackageParser(58): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl64582.tmp
03-17 17:44:40.398: D/PackageManager(58): Scanning package com.androidbook.simplelocation
03-17 17:44:40.398: E/PackageManager(58): Package com.androidbook.simplelocation requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
03-17 17:44:40.418: W/PackageManager(58): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.androidbook.simplelocation-1.apk
03-17 17:44:41.310: D/dalvikvm(58): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9265 objects / 448552 bytes in 868ms
03-17 17:44:41.655: D/AndroidRuntime(455): Shutting down VM
03-17 17:44:41.688: I/AndroidRuntime(455): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-17 17:44:41.765: D/dalvikvm(455): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
```

[image: Screen shots]

Comment: have you checked this tutorial on how to set up google map https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: google maps v1 is now deprecated and no longer used. You need to use google maps v2 in google play services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here**

Follow my post here to get working with Google Maps v2 and as @tyczj mentioned, Google maps v1 is deprecated so its preferred that you use the Google Maps v2.

Its a pretty easy implementation and I have what all stuff is required to get the maps working.

[Want to use GoogleMaps - OnMyLocationChangeListener but can't implement it? Any other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366923/want-to-use-googlemaps-onmylocationchangelistener-but-cant-implement-it-any/22442799#22442799)

Hope this helps you build the maps.