# Simple map based app not working

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to get a simple map based app running but when I install on device and try to "open" I receive the error "unfortunately application has stopped" On emulator I receive the message :

```
[2014-03-18 21:37:16 - FirstMap] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-03-18 21:37:16 - FirstMap] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-03-18 21:37:16 - FirstMap] Launch canceled!
```

Why do I receive this message ? I think my code looks good as I have followed these steps : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview ?

Here is my code :

```
MainActivity.java : 

package com.example.firstmap;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    }

}
```

main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="mykey"
/>
```

AndroidManifect.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstmap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.firstmap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to my post here:

[Want to use GoogleMaps - OnMyLocationChangeListener but can't implement it? Any other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366923/want-to-use-googlemaps-onmylocationchangelistener-but-cant-implement-it-any/22442799#22442799)

I have described what exactly to use and how.

Hope you find it helpful .. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many things missing from your manifest file. Try following the official instructions on how to use google maps [google map instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2)

The instructions you followed refer to version 1 google maps for android which is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Map Api V2, The important changes that you will have to make is

1) Make use of

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="android.app.DialogFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

i.e You have to use fragment tag in activity_main.xml instead of the mapview tag.

2) Refer Google play services.....

example: Google Maps Can't add reference to Play Services

Best Link to refer for newbies implementing Google Maps Api V2: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/