# Android Google Maps: error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm really new to Android Development, and some days I'm trying to put a map in my application. I tried some things, but without success. I appreciate if someone can help me.

Things I've done:

- Added the google-play-services_lib to my Package Explorer.
- Included android-support-v4.jar and google-play-services.jar as a dependency of my project.

I've tried several suggestions, but Google Maps APIs v2 Android doesn't work.

When running my project the following error appears:

```
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hellomap/com.example.hellomap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.example.hellomap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    ... 11 more
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4323000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the  element:     
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.B(Unknown Source)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.A(Unknown Source)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.gW(Unknown Source)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
06-15 20:31:37.666: E/AndroidRuntime(15687):    ... 20 more
```

**Here is main.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
map:mapType="normal"/>
```

**Here is manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.hellomap"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
     android:minSdkVersion="8"
     android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <!-- The following four permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

    <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyDD0f1pf-64LHNlTUWl6a5qeoWqqMw0e3s"/>

        <activity
         android:name="MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name">
             <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**and finally java**

```
package com.example.hellomap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Tank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my other post. I have explained the working of maps in detail.

You should be able to use maps now.

[Want to use GoogleMaps - OnMyLocationChangeListener but can't implement it? Any other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366923/want-to-use-googlemaps-onmylocationchangelistener-but-cant-implement-it-any/22442799#22442799)

Here's the layout snippet for maps I am using :

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

The permission are like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mike.mylocation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.mike.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapsexample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mike.mylocation.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUE API WILL GO HERE" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also Don't forget to use these **callbacks** or your battery will be drained..:p

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                1, this);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

If Having issues with the previous answer, here's how the code goes:

**1)** **In your MainActivity, extend the Fragment Activiy and implement LocationListener,
        OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener** like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,
        OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener {

private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

    GoogleMap map;
    List<Address> matches;
    String addressText;
    String addressLine;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    AppUtils mAppUtils;
    Context context;
    LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;

        if (servicesOK()) {
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            map = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service
            // LOCATION_SERVICE
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }

    }

@Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

        //This is the main stuff here. This is when the location is changed.
        @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

        map.addMarker(
                new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .title("My Location" + "\n")).showInfoWindow();

        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                marker.showInfoWindow();

                return false;
            }

        });


            //This is optional........................................................
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this);

        try {
            matches = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address bestMatch = (matches.isEmpty() ? null : matches.get(0));
        addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s", bestMatch
                .getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? bestMatch.getAddressLine(0)
                : "", bestMatch.getLocality(), bestMatch.getCountryName());
          //...........................................................................


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

//Check if the service is OK

public boolean servicesOK() {

        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

            return true;

        } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {

            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,
                    this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Cant connect!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                1, this);
    }
```

**2) Layout is the same as mentioned above.**

Hope this help.. :)